# Turn on auto-fill-mode when editing a commit message with Magit?

Tags: magit, git, auto-fill-mode, fill-column

I have tried:

```el
(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                                   (setq fill-column 72)
                                   (turn-on-auto-fill)))
```

1. In both cases, `auto-fill-mode` is not active in the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffer unless I manually turn it on with `M-x auto-fill-mode RET`.
2. Even when `auto-fill-mode` is turned on, I can still type past the 72nd character on the same line.

Also, correct me if I'm wrong but it seems both `git-commit-fill-column` and `git-commit-turn-on-auto-fill` are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `comment-auto-fill-only-comments` set to `t`. Since Magit commit buffer supports comments, it won't auto-fill.

```el
(use-package git-commit
  :ensure nil
  :preface
  (defun me/git-commit-set-fill-column ()
    (setq-local comment-auto-fill-only-comments nil)
    (setq fill-column 72))
  :config
  (advice-add 'git-commit-turn-on-auto-fill :before #'me/git-commit-set-fill-column))
```

**Edit**:
Created 2 issues on the subject: [#3067](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3067) and [#3068](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3068).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, neither `git-commit-fill-column` nor
`git-commit-turn-on-auto-fill` is deprecated, although the docstring
of `git-commit-fill-column` suggests that you use `fill-column`
directly.  (Before Magit 2.9.0, a buffer-local value for `fill-column`
was reset to `git-commit-fill-column`.)

`git-commit-turn-on-auto-fill` is still included in the
default value of `git-commit-setup-hook`, so Auto Fill mode should be
enabled by default.

I've justed tested the extreme example of

```
(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook (lambda () (setq fill-column 20)))
```

with `emacs -Q`, and it appears to work as expected (i.e., Auto Fill
mode is on with a `fill-column` of 20).

Comment: This is the second strange thing that I come accross without being able to pinpoint the origin, the first one being no color applied to faces in ERC. Time to bissect I suppose... Thanks for the clarifications though.

Comment: It wasn't officially obsolete because I forgot to mark it, but I've done it now: https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/a277432e806af89c3bdd6046721c4db948443120